# MS Access 2013 Change BackColor of Field if it contains string

Tags: ms-access, case, backcolor

I'm having trouble changing the color of my field when they containt certain words. Since the formatting rules are not working aswell i tried to write code.

Here's what i have:

```
Private Sub txtStatus_Exit(Cancel As Integer)
Select Case Me.Status
       Case "Verkauft"
       txtStatus.BackColor = vbRed
End Select
End Sub
```

The name of the field is txtStatus, actually it's a combination field with dropdown. What i doing wrong? I tried sever Actiontypes but it wont work :(

Comment: Have you tried something like: `If instr(txtStatus.value, "Verkauft") <> 0 then txtStatus.BackColor = vbRed`

Comment: ok this worked for now ... my form are continous tables ... it#s now changing the color for all tables when it checks if it's "Verkauft"

Is there a way to code that it only should change the current field

Comment: No. That's what _Format Conditions_ are for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should avoid combo fields by all means. They will cause you nothing but trouble as you've already seen.

The actual value is probably a number, thus:

```
Private Sub txtStatus_Exit(Cancel As Integer)

    Dim Status As Long

    Status = Me!txtStatus.Value
    ' Study value
    Debug.Print "Status:", Status

    Select Case Status
       Case 3    ' adjust to the value matching Verkauft. 
           Me!txtStatus.BackColor = vbRed
       Case Else
           Me!txtStatus.BackColor = vbWhite
    End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: i'll try this out in a sec. Actually i only see the Text behind eventhough is defined as number